# How to monitor or view network request from native side in react native(android and iOS)

Tags: react-native

I am using react native mapboxgl library to show map and layers. I want to see request and response which happening from native.

I can only see network request and response through Inspection-Network which happening through js.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of request and response you want to inspect?

Comment: Have you tried flipper?

Comment: flipper not log native request

Comment: I also tried https://www.charlesproxy.com/ but i counld not see native request.

Comment: @AkashSarkar I want to monitor network request which happen from native.

Comment: Have you tried reactotron?

Comment: reacttoron also monitor XMLHttpRequests js request. https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/plugin-networking.md

Answer (score 0):

After long time i got solution that using flipper and enable network it will native request log as well.

if anyone want to see api request monitor(native) you can download and enable network tab:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper